# Is it possible to programmatically manage Gmail messages quarantined through Google Workspace?

Tags: gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

My team is using Google Workspace's [quarantine feature](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6104172) to quarantine some Gmail messages.

We want to manage quarantined emails programmatically instead of through the interface in Google Workspace. We can't find any way to programmatically list or release/reject quarantined messages. Is there any way to do this?

The closest thing we found is [this endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-gmail-settings), but that seems to only allow us to fetch the history of actions admins already took for quarantined messages (released, rejected, etc.).

Huge thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this method is not currently available as part of the API. The methods you mention just list events of when things happened.  There is no way to actually manage quarantine via the API currently

I think its a really good idea.  You should consider posting a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191635%2B)

If you post the link to your feature request give it to me and i will star it as well.  It would be very useful.